# Pdb doesn't stop in a break point

Tags: python, pdb

I am using Pdb the debugger of Python. 
when I set a breakpoint in my callback, the Pdb doesn't stop there.
I used  :

```
continue
```

Comment: That's not how you set a breakpoint with pdb

Answer (score 1):

Use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` if you want to specify in your source code that the debugger should be invoked at that point.